# How to deserialize json response

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

```
[
    {
        "property1": "prop-00000001",
        "property2": "property2value1",
        "property3": {},
        "property4": [
            "Prop4-00000001",
            "Prop4-00000002"
        ]
    },
    {
        "property1": "prop-00000002",
        "property2": "property2value2",
        "property3": {},
        "property4": [
            "Prop4-00000003",
            "Prop4-00000004"
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm going to receive the json response as shown above. The number of items may increase for example as of now there are 2, it may go up depending on number of records in database. Another point is that values for each property shown above will always be similar to above format.

**My problem** is when I use class as below for casting in deserializing of json response, its not working:

```
public class Class1
{
    [JsonProperty("Property1")]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Property2")]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Property3")]
    public string Property3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Property4")]
    public IList<string> Property4 { get; set; }
}
```

**When I do :**

```
var jsonResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(Response.Content);
```

**Exception raised as :**

> Exception message: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: ". Path 'property3', line 1, position 60.

Which means that it is unable to ignore braces which lies as a value for property3: i.e {}.

**Stacktrace is :**

```
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParsePostValue(Boolean ignoreComments)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
```

How can I write the correct C# class or C# solution?

Comment: `Property3` isn't a `string` it represents a class... If you really want to get around the issue, just create an empty class, for example: `public class Property3
{
}` and then declare it like so `public Property3 property3 { get; set; }`

Comment: Thanks Codexer, now I got proper results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Property3 is not string. Its object. Your response json shows empty object ({}). So, define a class like

   `public class EmptyClass
   {
      // Add properties to this class based on your response.
   }`
2. Also, your property names and JsonProperty names does not match with response casing. So modify Class1 as below:

`

```
public class Class1
{
    // since your response json has camelCasing, you will need to define JsonProperty to represent camelCasing or just use public string property1 { get; set; } without any decoration.
    [JsonProperty("property1")]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("property2")]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("property3")]
    public EmptyClass Property3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("property4")]
    public IList<string> Property4 { get; set; }
}
```

3. After correcting the above two, since your response json is collection, you will need to deserialize to collection (**List< Class1 >**) as well. So, could you try using `var jsonResponse = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(Response.Content);`.

Please post your observations after making those changes.

Comment: Thanks Sam. That works like a charm. Now I get proper results. Thanks a lot for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the website http://json2csharp.com to you. There you can insert your JSON response and the site will generate a class construct based on it.

Here is the class I created based on your JSON:

```
public class Property3
{
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string property1 { get; set; }
    public string property2 { get; set; }
    public Property3 property3 { get; set; }
    public List<string> property4 { get; set; }
}
```